# Scheduled pipeline in gitlab using .gitlab-ci.yaml file

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-pipelines

I was trying to schedule a ci/cd pipeline in gitlab using .gitlab-ci.yaml file. I did't find a right documentation to implement the schedule using the ci/cd yaml file.
Is it possible to configure  a pipeline run schedule (say everyday 08:00 AM) in .gitlab-ci.yaml file?

Thanks
Arun

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, Scheduled pipeline is realized through GUI rather than .gitlab-ci.yml file in GitLab

You may find [this document](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html) useful if you want to use GUI for schedule pipeline. Configuring in GUI is simpler than yaml coding.

If you really want it to be configured in yaml file, you may create an issue in GitLab repo. Actually, there's already [an issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/296630) on this topic. It should not be a very difficult technically since it is only about keywords and parsing. Whether GitLab will do it or not is another story; so you'd better prepare a good scenario to persuade the GitLab team why you want this to be done.

Answer (score 2):

The scheduled pipelines are configured via the GitLab CI/CD UI.
[image]
[image]

[Read More](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html) about scheduled pipelines